# Navbar on small screens goes into a column instead of inline nav links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I keep the navigation links inline instead of it going into a column and taking up so much space on phone screens? right now its taking up like an inch on the phone.  I just want them to stay side by side.

```css
.navbar{
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.747);
  display: flex;
  float: none !important;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.nav-link,
.navbar-brand {
  flex: 1;
  color: var(--om);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 1.2rem;
  
}
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .navbar-brand ul li{
     width:100%;
   }
}
```

```html
<!--navbar-->
<!-- navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-default ">

  <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">     -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-value="home" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-value="about" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " data-value="photography" href="#photography">Photography</a>
    </li> -->
    
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " data-value="netlify" href="#netlify">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-value="reactNative" href="#apps">Apps</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " data-value="casestudies" href="#casestudies">Case Studies</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " data-value="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  </div>
enter code here
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```css
.navbar{
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.747);
  display: flex;
  float: none !important;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.nav-link,
.navbar-brand {
  flex: 1;
  color: var(--om);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 1.2rem;
  
}

    @media (max-width: 420px) {
      .nav-item {
        display:inline-block;
      }
    }
please try this:
```

```html
<!--navbar-->
<!-- navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-default ">

  <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">     -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-value="home" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-value="about" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " data-value="photography" href="#photography">Photography</a>
    </li> -->
    
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " data-value="netlify" href="#netlify">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-value="reactNative" href="#apps">Apps</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " data-value="casestudies" href="#casestudies">Case Studies</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " data-value="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  </div>
enter code here
</nav>
```

from 0 to 420px its to be `inline-block` . try this. if you want to change any size, you can increase 420 px to any size you want.